# How to get from index x to the last one in PHP explode()?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, explode, implode

I have a string:

```
$string = 'Index 1 - Index 2 - Index 3 - Index 4 - Index 5';
```

So I use: `$string2 = explode(" - ",$string);`

I would like to get Index 3 to the last index:

Index 3 - Index 4 - Index 5....

Like: `$newstring = $sring2[3-end($string2)];`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get part of an array. You pass it the array you want part of and the position you want to start it (minus one since arrays are zero-based keys).

```
$string = 'Index 1 - Index 2 - Index 3 - Index 4 - Index 5';
$array  = explode(" - ", $string);
$pos = 3;
$newarray = array_slice($array, $pos-1);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/200437)

Comment: Just add one more parameter to array_slice which is the number of elements to include in the new array: `array_slice($array, $pos-1, 1);`